# Can't access UserControl objects from other classes in WinForms Application

Tags: winforms, .net-4.5

I started re-grouping my forms with user controls and split containers on an existing application. Before I had a class called `GlobalFunctions` that had a method called `ResetAllForms()`. When I ran `GlobalFunctions.ResetAllForms()` from `frmMain` it would set all the properties in the form to the default values I wanted for them (disabled/enabled, visible or invisible.)

Before I was accessing them like `formName.Textbox1.Enabled = True` but now if I try to call them from the user control name like `UserControlA.Textbox1.Enabled = True` it gives me an error saying "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference". I know that means it was mean to instantiate a copy of the user control, but I am just dragging and dropping from the toolbox, so I don't know what its name is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is instating the user control in the back-end. I found it by using IntelliSense to find its name from the main form.

So inside my `GlobalFunctions.ResetAllForms()` method, I found it as `frmMain.UserControlA1.Textbox1`. So then I was able to set it like this;
`frmMain.UserControlA1.Textbox1.Enabled = True`

**Apparently when it is instantiated in the back-end it just adds a one to the user control name.**

Comment: While you can do it this way and it's a rapid way, but it's better to provide a public `ResetControls` method for your user controls and call it instead of accessing inner controls directly.

Comment: So what I hear you saying is you should create a method on each control to do it?

Comment: Not a mandatory rule, but it's better. Accessing to those properties is somehow against encapsulation. But it's a trade-off. You should look to your goal when you decide to put those controls in some user control. When you create a user control, one goal can be making your other parts of application independent from implementation and content of that user control, maybe you decide to use a masked text box instead of a text box, or maybe you decide to use a numeric up down instead of a text box, in such cases you only interact with the control using public methods and properties.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome :) If you are in the middle of a project, just keep this tip in mind for the next project and think about it and when you see it's what you need and it's applicable now, use the idea :)

Comment: I went back and rewrote everything to comply with this. It will make things easier in the long run.

Comment: Good choice. Good job! :)